# Help in Extending Least squares for sparse coefficients

Tags: time-series, estimation, matlab, lasso, moving-average

My observation `y` is obtained from the model, $y(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{p-1} r(i) x(n-i) + v(n)$ where `r` is the sparse channel coefficients, `x` is the one dimensional input and `v` is additive White Gaussian noise of zero mean. `y = filter(.)` command is used to model the above equation and thus creating an FIR filter or a moving average (MA) model. The order of the MA model is `p=3`.

So, $y = [y(1),y(2),....,y(100)]$ is a vector of 100 elements.  I am generating noise of variance `0.1` I want to estimate the sparse channel coefficients using LASSO. As there are `p` channel coefficients, I should get `p` estimates.

According to the equation of LASSO, `||rx - y||_2^2 + lambda * ||r||_1` I am estimating the sparse coefficients, `r`. As the true coefficient array contains `p` elements, I should get `p` estimated elements. I am not quite sure if this is the way to do. I have not found any example on LASSO being applied to univariate time series model such as ARMA. I don't know how to estimate the sparse coefficients using the appropriate algorithm and need help.

The first part of the Equation : $||rx - y||_2^2$ is  a least squares formulation which I can solve using Least Squares Approach. In order to implement LS, I have to arrange the input in terms of regressors. However, if the coefficients, $\mathbf{r}$ are sparse then I should use LASSO approach. I have tried using Matlab's LASSO function. For LASSO, I rearranged the input data $x$ in terms of regressors, but I don't know if this the correct approach.

I need help. Is there an approach to include the sparsity term in the LS?

Please find below the code for LASSO using Matlab function. As a toy example I am just assuming model order to be of lag 3 but I know that LASSO can be applied efficiently to a large model. I can test for larger order MA model having lag > 3.

---

```
% Code for LASSO estimation technique for 
%MA system, L = 3 is the order,  

%Generate input
 x = -5:.1:5;

r = [1    0.0   0.0];% L elements of the channel coefficients     
%Data preparation into regressors    
X1 = [ ones(length(x),1) x' x']; %first column treated as all ones since    x_1=1

y = filter(r,1,x); % Generate the MA model
[r_hat_lasso, FitInfo] = lasso(X1, y, 'alpha', 1, 'Lambda', 1, 'Standardize', 1);
```

OUTPUT :

The estimates returned are `r_hat_lasso = 0, 0.657002829714982, 0`

**Question :** This differs very much from the actual `r`.
Is my understandin wrong?

---

**UPDATE :** Based on the answer, I have tried to apply LASSO to a large MA model having 89 lags. I am trying to find out `lambda` using cross-validation. I have split the data into training and hold out sample denoted by the variables `iTr` and `iHo` respectively. I want to calculate the mean square prediction error between the the hold out samples in `y` and the predicted `y` obtained using the estimates. I am getting wrong values for MSE and unable to understand which estimated coefficients to use with the hold out samples in the lines `[r_hat_lasso, FitInfo] = lasso(X1(iTr,1:end), y(iTr));`

`[rhatLASSO,stats] = lasso(X1(iTr,2:end),y(iTr),'CV',10);`

`yLasso = X1(iHo,:)*rLasso;`

I am getting `NaN` as the error. Need help with the correct method to use cross validation and calculate the MSE? The code is below:

```
clear all
clc
    %Generate input
    N=200;
   x=(randn(1,N)*100);
    L = 90;
    Num_lags = 1:89;
    r = 1+randn(L,1);
    %Data preparation into regressors    
    r(rand(L,1)<.7)=0; % 70 of the coefficients are zero
    X1 = lagmatrix(x, [0 Num_lags]);

     y=X1*r ;

% %Estimation
 iTr = rand(N,1)<0.5; %training
 iHo = ~iTr;  % holdout


% %LASSO
 [r_hat_lasso, FitInfo] = lasso(X1(iTr,1:end), y(iTr));
 [rhatLASSO,stats] = lasso(X1(iTr,2:end),y(iTr),'CV',10);

% %Picking the hyper parameter, lambda
lassoPlot(rhatLASSO,stats,'PlotType','CV');
rLasso = [stats.Intercept(stats.Index1SE);rhatLASSO(:,stats.Index1SE)];

 stats.Index1SE
% 
% %ans =
% 
%  %   87
%  %Evaluate predictions on holdout  samples
  yLasso = X1(iHo,:)*rLasso;

%  %Assess prediction error
 fprintf('---MSE in holdout sample---\n');

  fprintf('MSE LASSO:  %f\n',mean((y(iHo)-yLasso).^2));
```

**OUTPUT : MSE LASSO:  NaN**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

> Is there an approach to include the sparsity term in the LS?

Well you wrote the cost function correctly: `||rx - y||_2^2 + lambda * ||r||_1`, this is usually solved using a method called [coordinate descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent), which Matlab uses in LASSO function. Other than that, you cannot use a closed form analytical solution as in the Least square case (also known as Ordinary Least Square, and the method is by using the [pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Linear_least-squares)).

Now to answer your actual question, yes you did something wrong in how you are building the *design matrix* (`X1` in your code).
This matrix should contain for each row the value of each regressor namely for the nth row:

- first column should be `x(n)`
- second column should be `x(n-1)`
- third column `x(n-2)`

So you will have undefined values for n < 3, you can replace them with `nan` or `0`, or discard them to be valid.

To create this matrix:

```
X1 = lagmatrix(x, [0 1 2]);
% If you also want to have intercept uncommment following line:
% X1 = [ones(length(x),1) X1];
```

This is the matrix you need to find coefficient of such models (ARMA). It contains one column for x, and the other for shifted versions of `x`. The maximum lag shift is the order of your MA model.

**NOTE**: The matrix `X1` will then contain rows with `NaN`, usually you are better off removing them. Though here, the Matlab `lasso` function deals with it.

Then fit for several values of lambda, using default option:

```
[r_hat_lasso, FitInfo] = lasso(X1, y);
```

`r_hat_lasso` will contain values of `r` for 39 different lambdas in this case. And you want to chose the one with the **lowest MSE** (look into `FitInfo.MSE`, first element will be lowest here: `0.0069`). Corresponding lambda is `FitInfo.Lambda(1) = 0.0833`. And:

```
r_hat_lasso(:,1)
% ans =
%   0.9708
%   0.0000
%   0.0000
```

Or simply use the correct Lambda directly:

```
[r_hat_lasso, FitInfo] = lasso(X1, y, 'alpha', 1, 'Lambda', 0.0833, 'Standardize', 1);
```

Finally to solve this same problem with *least-square* you can simply do:

```
% Removing NaNs:
X1(1:2,:) = []; y(1:2) = [];

% Now LS solution using psuedo-inverse, here with Matlab's backslash:
r_hat_ls = X1\y(:);
```

Will give you `r_hat_ls = [1 0 0]`.

---

**UPDATE:**

I also forgot that the `lasso` function add intercept term automatically so you do not have to `X1 = [ones(length(x),1) X1];` before calling `lasso`. I would advise to *zero-mean* your `y` anyway, such that any intercept would be `0`.

Regarding your `NaN`, it comes from the fact that `X1` contains rows with `NaN` (89 in your case), so `y` will also contains these at the beginning. Basically you have to imagine that you are looking at predictors that spann time 0 to `t=0-89`, where obviously you do not know what comes before 0 so the first 89 values are dummy. Simply do:

```
%Generate input
N=200;
x=(randn(1,N)*100);
L = 90;
Num_lags = 1:L-1;
r = 1+randn(L,1);
%Data preparation into regressors    
r(rand(L,1)<.7)=0; % 70 of the coefficients are zero
X1 = lagmatrix(x, [0 Num_lags]);

% NOW REMOVING NANS:
X1(1:L-1,:) = [];
y=X1*r ; % Note that now: length(y) = N - 89 

%Estimation
iTr = rand(N-L+1,1)<0.5; %training
iHo = ~iTr;  % holdout

%LASSO
[rhatLASSO,stats] = lasso(X1(iTr,:),y(iTr),'CV',10); % also 'CV' here does the cross validation for you so you do not really have to redo it...

%Picking the hyper parameter, lambda
lassoPlot(rhatLASSO,stats,'PlotType','CV');
% To use intercept
X1_withIntercept = [ones(length(y),1) X1];
rLasso_withIntercept = [stats.Intercept(stats.Index1SE);rhatLASSO(:,stats.Index1SE)];

%Evaluate predictions on holdout  samples
yLasso1 = X1_withIntercept(iHo,:)*rLasso_withIntercept;
% Or without intercept:
yLasso2 = X1(iHo,:)*rhatLASSO(:,stats.Index1SE);

%Assess prediction error
fprintf('---MSE in holdout sample---\n');
fprintf('MSE LASSO with Intercept:  %f\nMSE LASSO without Intercept:  %f\n',mean((y(iHo)-yLasso1).^2), mean((y(iHo)-yLasso2).^2));
```

Also consider having N large enough to train meaningfully (9 tenth, if you do 10-fold cross validation, of `N` should be significantly larger than your number of predictors, `L`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, a lot of concepts are cleared based on your explanation. However, there are 2 things which I could not follow properly - (1) how to correclty apply the estimates corresponding to the lowest MSE (2) how to use cross validation and evaluate the MSE performance. I have extended your code to a larger MA model presented uder the Update part of the Question. I am getting incorrect result. Could you please help in correctly applying the estimated coefficients so that I can obtain the MSE between `y` and `yLASSO`?

Comment: I think you got a bit confused, first why don't you use the first column of `X1` (by calling `lasso` on `X1(iTr,2:end)`)? Finally as I said you will have `NaN` in X1 (for all the rows where negative lags do not exist! i.e.  first 88 rows for `numLags=89`), so when you compute the prediction `yLasso`, you might have some `NaN` left, then the MSE, which calls `mean` will be `NaN`. Try using `nanmean`

Comment: Than you for the revised code. I ran the updated code but the MSE is very high : `MSE LASSO with Intercept:  99910.739554
MSE LASSO without Intercept:  88108.648107`
 I don't think MSE would be that high. Did you get this high MSE?

Comment: When I decrease the lag to say `L=10' then the MSE is lower. But for higher lags the MSE performance is so high. Can you please exxplain this?

Comment: Well, normally you would normalize your MSE differently if you have more or less predictors (e.g. `(y.^2-ypred.^2)/(n-L)` where `n` is number of samples and `L` number of predictors) otherwise you cannot really compare (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error#Regression)) then, Yes: it is absolutely normal to get such high values, since the variance of your y is roughly of that order (1e5). Plot `y(iHo)` and `yLasso` together, they're almost identical... If you want a measure of accuracy that is more intuitive use the coefficient of determination (pretty much a percent..)